# How can I deny test.ctp and allow home.ctp to anonymous users in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, authentication, cakephp-2.1

I'm using AuthComponent in CakePHP 2.

I want to show to anonymous users just the 'home' view and deny 'test' view.

Both views are inside the folder Views/Pages

If I use this code:

```
public function beforeFilter(){
    parent::beforeFilter(); //calling parents before filter
    $this->Auth->allow('home'); //allowing home only for pages controller
}
```

in my PagesController I'cant access any page of my PagesController, including home.ctp.

If I use:

```
$this->Auth->allow('display')
```

in my PagesController I can access any page of my PagesController, including test.ctp.

How can I solve this issue?

I tried to create a new method on my PagesController name home(). But without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good answer for you. 
[Allowing a Specific Page in Cakephp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836654/allowing-a-specific-page-in-cakephp)

Keep in mind that the Auth->allow is for methods. Display is the method in the pages controller. The Home page is considered a variable used in display. So you will have to do this programmatically in the Pages controller.

Answer (score 1):

**Situation one: If you dont want to utilize the default 'display' function of CakePHP.**

Along with creating a new method in PagesController named home(),
you must also alter the code in the file app\Config\routes.php as shown below to make it work for home and not for other methods, this new code redirects all queries to pages controller to home.ctp.

```
//default code statement:
Router::connect('/pages/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));
//New code
Router::connect('/pages/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'home'));
```

**Situation two: If you want to keep the default 'display' function of CakePHP**

Then you must build some redirect logic in display function when visitor is accessing test.ctp page, as also answered by @Chuck Burgess with a link.