# Auth for static page cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am new in cakephp..
I am making a website , there no users hierarchy , there is only the admin and public users.
**I want to disallow the public users from entering a certain static page.** of course the page is located in view/pages , so its view/pages/adminPanel.ctp  . 
please specify where I should include the code you will give.
Thank you in advance

here's my display function

```
function __checkLayout($pageName)   
            {
                //$pageName = "";

                $temp = "";

                switch ($pageName) 
                {
                    case "home":
                        $temp = "atheer";
                        break;
                    case "":
                        $temp = "atheer";
                        break;
                    case "adminpanel":
                        $temp = "adminview";
                        break;
                }
                return $temp;
            }


            public function display() {
    $path = func_get_args();
            //$this->layout='atheer';
            //$this->layout = Configure::read('layout.'.$page);
    $count = count($path);
    if (!$count) {
        return $this->redirect('/');
    }
    $page = $subpage = $title_for_layout = null;

    if (!empty($path[0])) {
        $page = $path[0];
    }
    if (!empty($path[1])) {
        $subpage = $path[1];
    }
    if (!empty($path[$count - 1])) {
        $title_for_layout = Inflector::humanize($path[$count - 1]);
    }
            $this->layout = $this->__checkLayout($page);

    $this->set(compact('page', 'subpage', 'title_for_layout'));

    try {
        $this->render(implode('/', $path));
    } catch (MissingViewException $e) {
        if (Configure::read('debug')) {
            throw $e;
        }
        throw new NotFoundException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Write a function that looks for a certain session variable, or less secure just a variable in the query string that only you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok if that is the case look at this [Allowing a Specific Page in Cakephp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836654/allowing-a-specific-page-in-cakephp),

Please take a look at the modified code:

```
    public $allowedPages = array('page1', 'page2'); //here you add allowed pages only

public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->allow('display');
}

function __checkLayout($pageName)   
            {
                //$pageName = "";

                $temp = "";

                switch ($pageName) 
                {
                    case "home":
                        $temp = "atheer";
                        break;
                    case "":
                        $temp = "atheer";
                        break;
                    case "adminpanel":
                        $temp = "adminview";
                        break;
                }
                return $temp;
            }


            public function display() {
    $path = func_get_args();
            //$this->layout='atheer';
            //$this->layout = Configure::read('layout.'.$page);
    $count = count($path);
    if (!$count) {
        return $this->redirect('/');
    }
    $page = $subpage = $title_for_layout = null;

    if (!empty($path[0])) {
        $page = $path[0];
    }
    if (!empty($path[1])) {
        $subpage = $path[1];
    }
    if (!empty($path[$count - 1])) {
        $title_for_layout = Inflector::humanize($path[$count - 1]);
    }
            $this->layout = $this->__checkLayout($page);

        if(!in_array($page, $this->allowedPages) && !$this->Auth->login()) {
            return $this->redirect('/login'); //here redirects to login page change the path if the path is different
        }
    $this->set(compact('page', 'subpage', 'title_for_layout'));

    try {
        $this->render(implode('/', $path));
    } catch (MissingViewException $e) {
        if (Configure::read('debug')) {
            throw $e;
        }
        throw new NotFoundException();
    }
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: it is not a function , its a static page

Comment: The static page in cakephp is done in PagesController, You should do it that way. Where did you put your static page?

Comment: I put it in app/view/pages but it doesnt have a function in the pages controller because I wont do any process in it

Comment: If you want help in the code, please post your display() function in pages controller here and 'll go from there

Comment: you are far too kind, I just added it

Answer (score 0):

You can put all the publicly accessible methods in `$this->Auth->allow('func1', 'func2'...)`;

If you want to allow all methods available for users then use `$this->Auth->allow('*')`.

[See the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#making-actions-public)

Comment: it is not a method , its a static page