# Allowing a static page get through login in cakePHP

Tags: php, authentication, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I have a static page I want to add to the existing cakePHP project. I managed to get around the Auth through using this code on PagesController

```
public $allowedPages = array('main',); 


public function beforeFilter() {
$this->Auth->allow('display');
}
public function display()
{
    $path = func_get_args();

    $count = count($path);
    if (!$count) {
        return $this->redirect('/');
    }
    $page = $subpage = null;

    if (!empty($path[0])) {
        $page = $path[0];
    }
    if (!empty($path[1])) {
        $subpage = $path[1];
    }
    $this->set(compact('page', 'subpage'));

    /*add CHU
    if(in_array($page, $this->allowedPages) || $this->User->loggedin) {
    $this->render($page);
    } */

    if(in_array($page, $this->allowedPages) ) {
        $this->render($page); //here redirects to login page change the path if the path is different
    }


    try {
        $this->render(implode('/', $path));
    } catch (MissingTemplateException $e) {
        if (Configure::read('debug')) {
            throw $e;
        }
        throw new NotFoundException();
    }
}
```

And added the route like this:

```
$routes->connect('/main', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display', 'main']);
```

But what's happening is that when a user logs in, the login page displays again. I think a validation should be added to check if a user is logged in here:

```
if(in_array($page, $this->allowedPages) ) {
        $this->render($page); //here redirects to login page change the path if the path is different
    }
```

How can I do this?

I tried these answers:
[Auth for static page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21536403/auth-for-static-page-cakephp)

[Allowing a Specific Page in Cakephp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836654/allowing-a-specific-page-in-cakephp)

Comment: By what you are doing there, you are bypassing authentication alltogether, which isn't an overly good idea. Try allowing specific pages via the auth component instead: **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18015096/cakephp-how-to-allow-unauthenticated-access-to-specific-pages/18018739#18018739**

Comment: What's the url and action of your login page? Is it written within PagesController?

Comment: @ndm, I added the class in the answer you recommended. I got the following errors and warnings without loading the page: 
`Strict (2048): Declaration of App\Controller\PagesController::beforeFilter() should be compatible with App\Controller\AppController::beforeFilter(Cake\Event\Event $event) [APP/Controller/PagesController.php, line 29]
Warning (4096): Argument 1 passed to App\Controller\AppController::beforeFilter() must be an instance of Cake\Event\Event, none given, called in /var/www/sty_reps/src/Controller/PagesController.php on line 34 and defined [APP/Controller/AppController.`

Comment: @ObjectManipulator, the url of the login page is sitename/login. sitename/ also redirects to /login. Those are defined in routes, not PageController

Comment: @YohanBlake The code example in your question would fail with the same error then. For future questions, please always mention your exact CakePHP version and tag your question accordingly! The error message is pretty clear, you need to use a compatible signature, and call the parent method accordingly. **[http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers.html#Cake\Controller\Controller::beforeFilter](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers.html#Cake\Controller\Controller::beforeFilter)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's necessary to go through so much hassle. For e.g: If the name of your action is "privacyPolicy", you could simply specify it within $this->Auth->allow() in AppController itself.

In case you'd like to keep it separated and write it within PagesController, I'd suggest you to call the parent function. Otherwise, the beforeFilter within PagesController overrides the beforeFilter of AppController.

```
   //AppController.php

  /* Other code */

  public function beforeFilter() {

  ..........

  $this->Auth->allow(array(
     "action1",
     "action2",
     "display"
   ));
  }
```

_____________________    OR    ________________________________

```
  // PagesController.php

   public function beforeFilter() {
      parent::beforeFilter(); // Add this line
      $this->Auth->allow('display');
   }
```

Hope this helps.

Peace! xD

Comment: The edit in the AppController works alright, but the problem now is that `mysite/` does not redirect to the /login page. Is it maybe because of the inclusion of `"display" ` in the allow array? This is the code in the route file that is supposed be doing the route:
 `$routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home']);`

Comment: basically, by doing what you mentioned, it works perfectly if a user is logged in. But if a user is not logged in, mysite/ does not redirect to mysite/login

Comment: @ObjectManipulator The pages controller serves all pages through a single action, so by unconditionally allowing the `display` action, you would allow access to _all_ pages, which is why the hassle of checking the requested page is neccessary.